# Custom View Helper vs Action View Helper in Zend Framework

Tags: model-view-controller, zend-framework

I was wondering when to call from the view a Custom View Helper like this one

```
<?php
class Zend_View_Helper_MyHelper
{
    public $view;

    public function setView(Zend_View_Interface $view)
    {
        $this->view = $view;
    }

    public function myHelper()
    {
        return $this->view->escape(
            ’This is being output from the custom helper <br />’
        );
    }
}
?>
```

and an action view helper.

Thanks.
Yehia A.Salam

Comment: What is the "action view helper"? There are view-helpers and action-helpers. view-helpers are for common code used in the view, action-helpers are used for common code used in the controllers.

Comment: http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.view.helpers.html scroll for the action view helper, they're called from inside the view, my question is when to use what, i could implement the same functionality using either method, but what is better suited for what, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why would you do this?

You could easily do:

```
class Zend_View_Helper_MyHelper extends Zend_View_Helper_Abstract
{
    public function myHelper()
    {
        return "This is output from the custom helper<br/>";
    }
}
```

and then do a:

`<?php echo $this->myHelper(); ?>`

on your view script

Comment: oh there is a Zend_View_Helper_Abstract already thanks for the tip. But still back to the main question, when should you use a custom view helper and not an action view helper, which is better suited for what

Comment: Usually you create a Custom View Helper when you have a repeated task in the view script. (Say render a <select> box with data from a model). The Action Helper on the other hand is used to inject functionality into the Controller Action without extending the default Zend_Controller_Action plugin. Personally I haven't had the need for a Custom Action Helper and usually extend the Zend_Controller_Action.

Comment: But where I put MyHelper.php in project directory and if I want to extend MyHelper class can I use it in another view helper as parent class?

Comment: If you are using modules in your application, Zend by default looks for the view helpers that are invoked in a view script in the corresponding /view/helper directory under your module. Otherwise you can explicitly define the view helpers path by doing: `$view = new Zend_View();  $view->addHelperPath("/path/","Prefix_"); $viewRenderer = Zend_Controller_Action_HelperBroker::getStaticHelper('ViewRenderer');$viewRenderer->setView($view);`

Answer (score 1):

In ZF, there are View Helper and Action Helper, which have been discussed here so so many times so I won't repeat.    But Ben asked "What is Action View helper?"
Action View Helper is a View Helper that calls an action of a controller.

Here is an example of Action View Helper from ZF manual:

```
    <div id="sidebar right">
    <div class="item">
       <?php echo $this->action('list',
                                'comment',
                                null,
                                array('count' => 10)); ?>
    </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: +1 for a clear explanation of "View Helper" vs. "Action Helper" vs. "Action View Helper"